# Why onEnter in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

```
onEnter
```

Why it is used along with router in reactjs? What is the purpose of it? I went through many sites but could not find the definition. I hope someone will help me to understand what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Route path="somePath" component={SomeComponent} onEnter={isUserAuthenticated}>
```

React onEnter is like a life cycle method. Just like componentDidMount. These are used for things like checking if the user is logged in Or some network infrastructure is available before entering into that route. In React-Router 4 it is no longer available. In the give ex only if the user is authenticated the route would be successful.